# Observable List Non-Changing on parent - @Ionic5/angular12 - @Input + Modal + nested components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, observable, subscription

So here is the problem:

I have a nested component `app-request-short` which triggers a Modal, which if button clicked, changes the "request.status" from pending to scheduled; when the modal is dismissed, the `app-request-long` parent of the previous one, should update the list ordering without refreshing the page (actually when the page refreshes it changes the order but not without refresh). How can I achieve to do so dynamically? Take a look on what I've already done + the explanatory Image.

I have this component schema (ionic Tabs template):

As it's said, an image is worth a thousand words:

[image]

--> serviceRequestService:
(the method WORKS properly)

```
updateServiceRequestById(serviceRequest: ServiceRequest): Promise<ServiceRequest> {
    const API_URL = `${this.serviceRequestJSON}/${serviceRequest.id}`;
    const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return  this.http.put<ServiceRequest>(API_URL, serviceRequest, {headers: header}).toPromise();
  }
```

--> Output from modal/popup when clicked for `scheduled()`:

[image]

--> Modal ts:

```
dismiss() {
    this.modalController.dismiss({
      dismissed: true
    });
  }

  scheduled(request: ServiceRequest){
    if(request.status === ReqStatus.pending){
      request.status = ReqStatus.scheduled;
    }
    console.log('changed');
    this.requestService.updateServiceRequestById(request).then((resp)=>{
      console.log(resp);
      this.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

--> requestTab
--html:

```
<ion-content>
  <ng-container *ngIf='serviceRequestsParent'>
    <app-request-long [serviceRequests]='serviceRequestsParent'></app-request-long>
  </ng-container>
</ion-content>
```

-- ts:

```
export class RequestTabPage implements OnInit {

  serviceRequestsParent: ServiceRequest[]=[];
  private subscriber: Subscription;

  constructor(private serviceRequestService: ServiceRequestService) {
    this.subscriber = this.serviceRequestService.getAllServiceRequests().subscribe((resp)=>{
      console.log('subscriber loop');
      this.serviceRequestsParent = resp;
      console.log(resp);
    });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ionViewWillLeave(){
    this.subscriber.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

--> app-request-long

```
 <ion-item-divider (click)="activeClick()" color='primary'>
  <ion-label>ACTIVE</ion-label>
  <ng-container *ngIf='!isActive.active then hidden else shown'></ng-container>
</ion-item-divider>
<ion-item-group [ngClass]='isActive.active ? "shown" : "hidden"' *ngFor="let request of activeArray; last as isLast">
    <app-request-short style='width: 100%;' [serviceRequest]='request' [requestedDate]='request.requestedDate'></app-request-short>
</ion-item-group>
<ion-item-divider (click)="scheduledClick()" color='primary'>
  <ion-label>SCHEDULED</ion-label>
  <ng-container *ngIf='!isActive.scheduled then hidden else shown'></ng-container>
</ion-item-divider>
<ion-item-group [ngClass]='isActive.scheduled ? "shown" : "hidden"' *ngFor='let request of scheduledArray'>
    <app-request-short style='width: 100%;' [serviceRequest]='request' [requestedDate]='request.requestedDate'></app-request-short>
</ion-item-group>
<ion-item-divider (click)="pendingClick()" color='primary'>
  <ion-label>PENDING</ion-label>
  <ng-container *ngIf='!isActive.pending then hidden else shown'></ng-container>
</ion-item-divider>
<ion-item-group [ngClass]='isActive.pending ? "shown" : "hidden"' *ngFor='let request of pendingArray'>
    <app-request-short style='width: 100%;' [serviceRequest]='request' [requestedDate]='request.requestedDate'></app-request-short>
</ion-item-group>
```

-- TS:

```
@Input() serviceRequests: ServiceRequest[];
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
    this.serviceRequests = changes.serviceRequests.currentValue;
    this.sortByStatus(changes.serviceRequests.currentValue);
  }
```

--> app-request-short

```
<ion-item button (click)="openModal($event)" class="item-insider">
  <ion-text style='font-size: 14px;'>{{requestedDate | date:'mediumDate'}}</ion-text>
  <ng-container style="font-size: 12px;"  *ngFor="let sD of serviceRequest.serviceDestinations; last as isLast">
    <div class="textIon">
      <b>{{sD.type | destinationType}}</b>
      {{sD.location.city}}, {{sD.location.zipCode}}
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngIf='!isLast then direction'></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf='serviceRequest.status === reqStatus.pending.valueOf() then pendingAction'></ng-container>
</ion-item>
```

-- TS:

```
export class RequestShortComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() serviceRequest: ServiceRequest;
  @Input() requestedDate: string;

  reqStatus = ReqStatus;

  constructor(private modalController: ModalController) {
    console.log();
   }

  ngOnInit() {}

   openModal($event){
     console.log(event);
     this.presentModal();
   }

  private async presentModal(){
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ServiceRequestDetailsPage,
      backdropDismiss:true,
      showBackdrop:true,
      componentProps:{
        request: this.serviceRequest
      }
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is a bit confuse for me, but I can tell you that to update a  `@ViewChild` you have to use `@Input()` decorator, and to update a parent component you have to use the `@Output()` decorator.

Comment: I thought that the image should help for the explanation, what i have so far is a grandparent - parent - childs schema, the childs can trigger a modal that changes data on a JSON-server by http put method, doing this, the modal will dismiss and the grandparent have to get the updated data using the `getAllServiceRequests()` method passing it to the parent by `@Input` which actually doesn't do until page is refreshed. Doing a bit of research I've realised that maybe I shall be using Subject to get the data updated tell me what you think about it!!

Comment: Sure, this short explanation help me better.  Seems me that `getAllServiceRequests()` doesn't detect changes, it still freeze after the Modal close. To update the parent component from a Chield you have to use `@Output()` like: `@Output() serviceRequestsParent: ServiceRequest[]=[];`. So, in the Modal dismiss in update service `this.requestService.updateServiceRequestById(request)` you can put the `this.serviceRequestsParent = resp;` to receive directly the data and update the parent view.